How can I create netflix like application for my parents for android tv
I want to prepare for my parents a small gift for anniversary. I tought I would like to prepare Netflix like application where instead on online films/movies our home made recordings will be displayed. Like taken from outside SSD. Are you awere of any tutorial for such kind of information? Of course I do not need any login/register stuff - just simple home player app where I can have categories, miniatures and stuff. Like instead of Horror - Birthdays etc.
I was searching for proper tutorial in the open search, however I was not able to fine any proper tutorial that would help me with this stuff; I am no pro I just hope it is possible to help me with providing any tutorial that would allow me to make this present real.
thanks

There are already some home hosting applications that can you help you achieve this, e.g. Plex, that let's you host your files and has an application that can run on TVs
(There are also some FOSS alternatives, you should search those too)
